# Tracing Openstack Mitaka

Tags: profiling, openstack, openstack-nova, zipkin

I'm trying to trace services in Openstack Mitaka using osprofiler, but i'm having some issues. It seems it's not possible to trace nova service in Mitaka using osprofiler (correct me if i'm wrong). So i was thinking of using Zipkin.
Can anyone tell me if Zipkin integrates with openstack mitaka?

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack does not have Zipkin as an inbuilt tracer. Hence OSProfiler was adopted as a standard project for tracing in OpenStack.

As far as i can see from the documentation, Nova should have OSProfiler support for Mitaka. Although i have not used OSProfiler with Mitaka, I have worked with OSProfiler with Newton and subsequent releases.

You can post the issue that you are facing so that it will be easier to debug.